# Unable to Exchange Uber API authorization code for an access token for fetching current trip details

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, uber-api

Once the Uber user authenticates and authorizes my app, i am receiving an authorization code but i am unable to exchange authorization code for an access_token.

I am trying to fetch current trip info using :
**https://developer.uber.com/docs/trip-experiences/references/api/v1-requests-current-get**

```
// uber.php

echo $_GET['code']."<br>";
$token = curl_init();

$param = array(
    'client_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'client_id' => '_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/uber/uber.php', // (the same as in app settings)
    'code' => "{$_GET['code']}"
    );

$postData = '';
foreach($param as $k => $v)
    {
       $postData .= $k . '='.urlencode($v).'&';
    }
$postData = rtrim($postData, '&');
curl_setopt($token, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token');
curl_setopt($token, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($token, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($token, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($token, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
$returned_token = curl_exec($token);
curl_close($token);

echo "<hr>";
echo $returned_token;
echo "<hr>";
```

I am getting a blank output.

Comment: There is likely an error in your post parameters. You should use the community php sdk: https://github.com/stevenmaguire/uber-php

Comment: addded this : curl_setopt($token, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));

Answer (score 1):

addded this :

```
curl_setopt($token, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
```

and the problem was solved... :-)